# Power BI Tile Size and Multiple Images in One Tile?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I'm looking to see how I can either shrink tiles further down in Power BI than the drag features lets me, or a way to display multiple images from different API endpoints in the same tile.

For example here is a SonarQube image output separated to each tile as an IMG tile.

[image]

As you can see this takes up a ton of dead space and could be done in a much more compact way.  Being able to paste all 4 images in one box would already help.

I did try to use the "Embed Code" option, but I could get an image to show since it's technically not an image (.jpg or something like that), but instead an endpoint (ex: http://server:9000/api/project_badges/measure?project=Project&metric=metric_name).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, answer was simple, I needed to include a p element and close it before each endpoint in the embedded tile code.

```
<p><img src="http://server:9000/api/project_badges/measure?project=Project_name&metric=metric_name1"></p>
```